# Remove excess information in verification email sent to users?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

The email sent to users to verify is

> https://YOUR_APP_ID.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action?mode=verifyEmail&oobCode=sGgyIp-CMasddaNXGw4daIt5kASKDJasdhoq3rysAAAF06gx6Jg&apiKey=API_KEY

Is there any way to remove or shuffle them? I really don't want anyone seeing my project ID and the other information from the link

Answer (score 0):

That's not a feature that Firebase Authentication offers for [email verification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth) links.  You can [file a feature request with Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) to express your opinion.